# Issue when zooming in and panning down on UIScrollView with UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIScrollView` (self.mainScrollView) of frame 320x568 in my `ViewController` having a `UIImageView` (self.vehicleImageView) of same size and enabled zooming on `UIImageView`.

`UIImageView` contains a single image of 450x225. It will be scaled and fitted into `UIImageView`.(see below image 1)

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

**The problem I’m having is when I zoom into my `UIImageView`, and then I pan/scroll down – I can drag well past my image and see a large area of the `UIImageView`'s background. The further I'm zoomed-in, the more of the `UIScrollView`'s background is exposed. So the issue is that the space around image is also zoomed along with UIImageView (See above image 2. In this image the scrollview is panned all the way to top-left)**

Here's what i have in my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.vehicleImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.vehicleImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"]];
    self.mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale=3.0;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.vehicleImageView;
}
```

P.S. You will find this question repititive but I had to ask this question since I couldnt find any working answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to adjust contentSize of the scrollView. The contentSize is the internal 'scrollable' area. Are you adjusting contentSize at all?

Comment: I have tried to set ImageView's content size to Image's size to stop the extra space around image to also zoom along with it, but it doesnt work

Comment: ImageView's contentSize? I meant the scrollViews contentSize, as I understand it you zoom using the scrollView?

Comment: Yes sorry Scrollview not imageview

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by getting code for zooming in uiscrollview from MWPhotoBrowser library.